# Windows 10 System Tray - Collect Other Icons in a Box

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, notification-area

How do we collect (not hide or remove) other icons from the system tray in box, instead of showing them all on the task bar? My PC has this problem where all the icons are displayed instead of tucked in a box that you can hide or show by clicking a button.

Windows 10

[image]

Comment: If Windows 10 then Right Click on Taskbar -> Taskbar Settings ->Notification Area (Select which icons appear on taskbar) may be in your case 'Always show all icons in the notification area' option is Enabled. Please check. If so Turn it off and decide from the list below, which ones you want to display and  others being hidden.

Comment: @patkim this should be an answer with a screenshot! don't forget right click in an empty area on the taskbar.

Comment: @patkim your comment solves my problem, but I don't know how to convert it into an answer. Thanks by the way!

Comment: @Moab - Since OP did not mention the Windows version I just left it as a comment. Now that OP has confirmed that it worked, I will post it as an answer. Thanks for mentioning that one should right click the empty area of the taskbar.

Comment: They did in the Title! Added it to the tags.

Comment: Oh yes, somehow missed it completely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your Windows 10 OS, right click the empty area on your taskbar.
2. Click on Taskbar Settings
3. Scroll down to section named Notification Area
4. Click on 'Select which icons appear on the taskbar'
5. Turn off the option 'Always show all icons on the taskbar'
6. Then choose from the list there below what icons you wish to display in the notification area
7. Others will be then hidden and will be seen when you click 'Show hidden icons' arrow on the taskbar in the notification area.

See the below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could this (https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker-v2-0) help?